# Access to data from a previous Promise in a chain

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

my problem is I want access to data fetched from a previous then(), how can i do it ?
(requirement : I cannot modify externalBuiltInFunction() )

```
ajaxCall(...)
.then( (response) => {                          
    return response.json();
})
.then ( (jsonData) => {
    return externalBuiltInFunction(jsonData);
})
.then ((dataFromExternalFunction) => {
   ... here i want to use jsonData, how can i do ?...
}
```

Thx for the help

Comment: Each function takes what was returned from the previous function so return `jsonData` in the previous function, though there maybe a better way to organise the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use just one `then` statement with `async/await`:

```
ajaxCall(...)
  .then(async response => {                          
    const jsonData = await response.json();
    const external = await externalBuiltInFunction(jsonData);
    // Here you still have access to jsonData and external 
  })
```

Comment: And if async/await is unavailable, `Promise.all` serves as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can store `jsonData` in a variable in the outer lexical environment:

```
let jsonData;

ajaxCall(...)
    .then( (response) => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then ( (jsonData) => {
        jsonData = jsonData;
        return externalBuiltInFunction(jsonData);
    })
    .then ((dataFromExternalFunction) => {
        // jsonData is available here
    }
```

Alternatively, you can pass `jsonData` to the next `.then` explicitly as an array with result of `externalBuiltInFunction` call:

```
ajaxCall(...)
    .then( (response) => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then ( (jsonData) => {
        return Promise.all([externalBuiltInFunction(jsonData), jsonData]);
    })
    .then (([dataFromExternalFunction, jsonData]) => {
        // jsonData is available here
    }
```